# Remove spaces between tag and expressions

Tags: angularjs

In Handlebars [whitespace control](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#whitespace-control),

```
<p>  {{my_age}}    </p>   -->   <p> 20 </p>   # has space between  > {{  and  }} < 
<p>  {{~my_age~}}  </p>   -->   <p>20</p>     # ~ tilde removes space between
```

Any equivalent syntax in Angularjs?  Without writing filters/things in js (I am new to Angularjs).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that with `{{}}` syntax as I know.

But it's possible to use `ng-bind="expression"` or `ng-bind-html="expression"`, then AngularJS will bind data itself